# how to select a div among sets of divs with thesame class name and contained in a main container div

Tags: jquery

hi to every one  i am new in jquery. i want to make an  app using the drag and  drop events in  jquery.but i am NOT  able to select a div among a set of divs with thesame name contained in a main div.please can anybody help me ?
note these set of divs are generated dynamically ,getting the data from the database

Comment: can you post some sample markup, it may help to get a better answer

Comment: I think you should give more explanation. What's special with that div, and why don't you just use the id-attribute ...

Comment: hi... Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: New user, folks. Chill out with the down votes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just really tough to tell exactly what you need.

I sounds like you have elements that are generated dynamically in your javascript, and you are having trouble making those draggable.

I assume this means that you have successfully made other elements on the page draggable that were not added dynamically.

IF this is the case, before you add your new element to the page, just do the same `draggable()` call on it before you add it.

```
   // Create new element
var $newElement = $("<div class='suggestion'>I'm a suggestion</div>");

   // Make it draggable
$newElement.draggable();

   // Append it to your container
$newElement.appendTo('.suggestions');
```

If this is not what you mean, then please be very clear and detailed in your question. Please also add a code example, which often explains much. :o)

Comment: thanks very much .it worked  this  very helpful. once more thank your very much . great!!!!

Comment: @fon - You're welcome. :o) If this answers your other question as well, you should probably delete that one so there isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

To select a specific div, give it an ID.

```
<div class="container">
  <div>content</div>
  <div id="target">content</div>
</div>
```

`$('#target')` will let you get that specific div.

If you need to get a particular element in a list you can use the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function.

```
$('.container').eq(1)
```

will get the #target div

Comment: thanks for your answer.but the issue is the children divs are generated dynamically from the database so i want to use the mousedown event to getone of the generated divs  within the main div
 <div class="suggestions">
     inside here are the dynamically generated divs and i want the div click at that moment
     </div>

Comment: Those kind of usage cases are a great help in getting you the right info - sometimes the answer isn't the path you might think, so having some more background as to _why_ you're trying to do something helps us out a bunch :) happy coding