# how to i access dynamically create div or elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have made a ajax  request and the various rows gotten I echo each into a dynamically created the div. Now I want to bind a event to each of these divs like mousedown() ..  do something but I am not able to access any of the divs. Please can any one help me with that?

Comment: Your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078634/ seemed to be centered around making them draggable. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Dynamically created elements are accessed the same way as any other element. If it's not working for you, you are doing something wrong, but it's impossible to say what unless you show some concrete code.

Answer (score 3):

if your using jQuery 1.7+ you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) as [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is depreciated.

```
jQuery("table").on("click", "tr", function(event){});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$(".myDivClass").live('mousedown', function() {
  alert('Your mouse is down!');
});
```

[You can view a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz2Ur/)

It doesn't bind an event to those new divs, it just executes the function/handler whenever a `mousedown` happens in an element matching that class (determined via bubbling), getting the effect you want...as if you bound the handler to each new div that appears.

Answer (score 0):

and another solution, than `.live()`

You can just load the jquery function dinamycally, in your ayax request.
it's not usefull in small tasks, but in large projects it can be very usefull (from my practice...)