# How to find dynamically added html control using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, dom

I have a literal control on my ASP.Net web page. In my code behind function, I am assigning a javascript  block to this literal's Text. This script block points to a website URL which returns a html output back to the literal and as a result it gets rendered on my page dynamically.

Page HTML

`<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="MyLiteral" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>`

Code behind

```
MyLiteral.Text = String.Format(@"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywebsite/gethtml'></script>";
```

After this page loads completely, I want to access one of the html elements, say DIV (dynamically created above) using JQuery code like this

```
alert($('#mydynamicdiv').attr('id'));
```

However, this alert returns undefined. Why does this happen basically, and how can I access the dynamic elements here?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079105/how-to-i-access-dynamically-create-div-or-elements-with-jquery

Comment: You can use on function. for eg. $(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 alert($('#<%=mydynamicdiv.ClientID%>').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use on function.

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
$(document).on('click','.myDiv',function(){ ... });
```

Just Try.